# como corrijo este error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION FN_CARGAS(P_RUT IN NUMBER, P_ISAPRE IN VARCHAR2, P_PERIODO IN NUMBER) 
RETURN NUMBER AS NRO NUMBER :=0
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Error(2,14): PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "end-of-file" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pareciera que estás trabajando con PL/SQL: ¿y el `BEGIN`, `END`, `RETURN`? No olvides aprender primeramente la [sintaxis](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php).

Comment: Al pedacito de código que pones le falta `;` al final.